# Fuzzy logic operator symbols

Tags: symbols, logic, relation-symbols

How can I write in Latex symbols for standard or Łukasiewicz conjunction like these?

[image: screenshot]

Thank you

Comment: It looks like `\mathop{\tt and}\nolimits` in plain TeX...

Comment: What about `\wedge`?

Comment: can you cite a published reference where these are used, please?  (an arXiv article or other on-line reference would be most convenient.)

Comment: It's my homework assignment: https://cw.felk.cvut.cz/wiki/_media/courses/ae4m33rzn/fl_assignment.pdf Here are lecture slides: https://cw.felk.cvut.cz/wiki/_media/courses/ae4m33rzn/p11_fl_relations.pdf

Comment: You could be also interested by `$\widehat{p}$`.

Comment: the example shown in the slides (p.49 according to adobe reader) appears to use `\underset` (from `amsart`) as the "S" is clearly not snugged up into the wedge.  but it's probably somewhat a matter of taste, so the answer by @StevenSegletes seems to satisfy that condition.  (but it isn't a new symbol to be considered by unicode, which is why i asked for a reference.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This keeps the "S" and "L" in non-italic upshape, as given in your example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document} 
$ a \mathrel{\stackunder[-1pt]{$\wedge$}{\tiny L}} 
  b \mathrel{\stackunder[-1pt]{$\wedge$}{\tiny S}} c$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need them in subscripts or superscripts, here's a way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\landl}{\mathbin{\landx{L}}}
\newcommand{\lands}{\mathbin{\landx{S}}}

\newcommand{\landx}[1]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\land$\cr
    \noalign{\kern.5ex}
    \hidewidth$\scriptscriptstyle#1\mkern1.5mu$\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}

\begin{document}
$a\landl b\lands c$
\end{document}
```

[image]